# Number of binary rooted trees with anti-commutative property fixed by $\sigma \in S_n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, combinatorial-proofs

Let $B(n)$ be a set of leaf-labelled inequivalent binary rooted trees. $S_n$ be a symetric group. We say that $\gamma\in B(n)$ fixed by some $\sigma\in S_n$, if $\sigma(\gamma)=\gamma$ . Here is an example in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUMRB.png).

The number of leaf-labelled rooted binary trees fixed by $\sigma$ is calculated by the given formula: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwZ9B.png), where $\lambda$ is a partition type of $\sigma$. For instance type of $(12)(3)(4)(5)\in S_5$ is $(2,1,1)$, $(1234)(56)(7)\in S_7$ is $(4,2,1).$

In the anti-commutative case I do not have an idea how to find the number of $\gamma\in B(n)$ fixed by some $\sigma\in S_n$. Can someone give an idea where can I start. By the context "anti-commutative case" I mean, for some $\gamma\in B(n)$, we can have $\sigma(\gamma)=-\gamma$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.